# Documentations for Numpy Functions in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to display documentation of numpy functions from jupyter notebook?

help(linspace) did not work for me

Comment: ?np.linspace should work

Comment: Have you done `from numpy import linspace`? Otherwise you should do `help(np.linspace)`

Comment: The marked duplicate Q&A has a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?` in `jupyter` to show `docstring`. In your case try to run the following command:

```
?np.linspace
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Highlight and press `SHIFT` + `TAB`.